# Hilbertspace weak convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I have following Problem:

Given is a Hilbert space $H$ and subspaces $H_n$ with $H_n \subset H_{n+1}$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\cup_{n=1}^\infty H_n$ dense in H
Also there is a $x' \in H'$ and a coercive  continous sesquilinear form $a: H \times H \rightarrow \mathbb{K}$

i) $x_n$ sequence in $H$: $x_n \rightarrow x \Leftrightarrow x_n \rightharpoonup x$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} a(x_n,x_n) \rightarrow a(x,x)$;

ii) For all $n$ there exists exactly one $x_n \in H_n$, so that

$a(y,x_n) = x'(y)$  for $y\in H$

and the sequence is bounded;

iii) $(x_n)$ sequence as defined in (ii)  and $x \in H$ solution of
$a(y,x) = x'(y)$  for $y\in H$
Show strong convergence, i.e. $x_n \rightarrow x$ for $n \rightarrow \infty$

For i) the weak convergence follows directly and the convergence in sesquilinearform is basically due to it being continous?
I dont know about ii) and iii)